# Blogs build using Fusion Builder need to export in normal wordpress site admin

Tags: database, wordpress, post

Im having a problem regarding migrating the avada blogs to normal wordpress admin.
i have imported the file from the 1st instance i.e avada to 2nd instance i.e normal.it imported with fusion builder shortcodes. which are reflecting in my frontend as well as backend.
how to get rid of it.

I tried to remove manually but its heck of a task.
Also tried certains plugins but nothing helped me.